# AngularJS $locale service doesn't return correctly language

Tags: angularjs, locale

I am trying to get locale from `$locale` service
my current browser using French(Switzerland) but the `$locale` service doesn't return correctly.
I did a try here:

[Example angularjs $Locale](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPLnrVhqONGduqqhh29l?p=preview)

Did I make some mistake here, please guide me on it.